# How to find instance of characters in string (not a substring)

Tags: bash

I have been looking into this and can't seem to find an answer.

I have a file name stored in string FILENAME

```
FILENAME="my%fi;le.dat"
```

I am traversing a directory trying to find files that contain any of these characters:

```
BAD_CHARS="%^();,"
```

How can I determine (with bash or tool) if any (1 or more) of those characters are in the filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `bash`'s regex matching `=~`:

```
$ [[ "$FILENAME" =~ ["$BAD_CHARS"] ]] && echo "bad name!" || echo "valid name"
bad name!
```

where `["$BAD_CHARS"]` forms *regex character class* `[%^();,]`

Comment: Thanks, that is the code I needed.  Thanks for the quick response, seems the gods don't think my programming question is a programming question and want to close it.

Comment: @JohnW, you're welcome. The community expects the author of a question to show his/her efforts/code to solve the proclaimed issue. That's the rule you need to follow. Please follow it in all your practical questions